# Save PApplet frame as image on disk not working

Tags: java, image, processing, unfoldingmap, papplet

I am making a map with [unfolding](http://unfoldingmaps.org) with processing.core.PApplet. I'm using pure Java instead of Processing (Java 8).

My goal is to save the map as an image on my hard drive, but when I try to save it as a PNG, it is a black image. Same blank result happens when trying to save it as a TIF or JPG.

The map itself has no event dispatcher. You cannot interact with it, no clicking, zooming nor scrolling. It should have no problem saving as an image.

My Main code is quite simple:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet sketch = new ChoroplethMap();
        sketch.init();
        sketch.save("test.jpg");
    }
}
```

I've also tried the `saveFrame()` method as well to no avail. From other forums, it seems like these methods have no issues in Processing but I've found no information on them in pure Java 8.

I've also tried using BufferedImages and streams but it yields the same result: a black image with no map.

Here's my map code, it is pretty much copied from the unfolding library Choropleth map example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import processing.core.PApplet;

import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.data.Feature;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.data.GeoJSONReader;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.examples.SimpleMapApp;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.examples.interaction.snapshot.MapSnapshot;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.marker.Marker;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;

/**
 * Visualizes population density of the world as a choropleth map. Countries are shaded in proportion to the population
 * density.
 * 
 * It loads the country shapes from a GeoJSON file via a data reader, and loads the population density values from
 * another CSV file (provided by the World Bank). The data value is encoded to transparency via a simplistic linear
 * mapping.
 */
public class ChoroplethMap extends PApplet {

    UnfoldingMap map;

    HashMap<String, DataEntry> dataEntriesMap;
    List<Marker> countryMarkers;

    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600, OPENGL);
        smooth();

        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 700, 500);
        map.zoomToLevel(2);
        map.setBackgroundColor(240);
        //MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);

        // Load country polygons and adds them as markers
        List<Feature> countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "data/countries.geo.json");
        countryMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(countries);
        map.addMarkers(countryMarkers);

        // Load population data
        dataEntriesMap = loadPopulationDensityFromCSV("data/countries-population-density.csv");
        println("Loaded " + dataEntriesMap.size() + " data entries");

        // Country markers are shaded according to its population density (only once)
        shadeCountries();
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(255);

        // Draw map tiles and country markers
        map.draw();
    }

    public void shadeCountries() {
        for (Marker marker : countryMarkers) {
            // Find data for country of the current marker
            String countryId = marker.getId();
            DataEntry dataEntry = dataEntriesMap.get(countryId);

            if (dataEntry != null && dataEntry.value != null) {
                // Encode value as brightness (values range: 0-1000)
                float transparency = map(dataEntry.value, 0, 700, 10, 255);
                marker.setColor(color(255, 0, 0, transparency));
            } else {
                // No value available
                marker.setColor(color(100, 120));
            }
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, DataEntry> loadPopulationDensityFromCSV(String fileName) {
        HashMap<String, DataEntry> dataEntriesMap = new HashMap<String, DataEntry>();

        String[] rows = loadStrings(fileName);
        for (String row : rows) {
            // Reads country name and population density value from CSV row
            String[] columns = row.split(";");
            if (columns.length >= 3) {
                DataEntry dataEntry = new DataEntry();
                dataEntry.countryName = columns[0];
                dataEntry.id = columns[1];
                dataEntry.value = Float.parseFloat(columns[2]);
                dataEntriesMap.put(dataEntry.id, dataEntry);
            }
        }

        return dataEntriesMap;
    }

    class DataEntry {
        String countryName;
        String id;
        Integer year;
        Float value;
    }

}
```

I feel like I'm not initializing the PApplet in my main class the right way. Is there anything else I need to do besides calling the `init()` method?

I'm open to over suggestions besides trying to fix `save()` or `saveFrame()`, something like using BufferedImages or streams to write to a file.

Thanks, and have a nice day.

Comment: > it is pretty much copied from the unfolding library Choropleth map --  Why not just run it in Processing?

Comment: @apodidae I want it to work in Java so I can export my project as a jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the PApplet launch ? If it does, could you get away by calling `save()`/`saveFrame()` from within the PApplet ?

E.g.

```java
 public void draw() {
        background(255);

        // Draw map tiles and country markers
        map.draw();
        save("test.jpg");
        noLoop();// alternatively just exit(); if you don't need the PApplet window anymore.
    }
```

Does it make a difference if you call `sketch.loadPixels();` before `sketch.save()` ?

I also wonder if you've got any guarantees that the sketch finished initialising and rendering at least a frame when you call save. (AFAIK rendering happens on a separate thread (the animation thread)).

To test this idea you can use `registerMethod("draw",this);`

> Register a built-in event so that it can be fired for libraries, etc. Supported events include:
> ...draw – at the end of the draw() method (safe to draw)

e.g.  (not tested, but hopefully illustrates the idea):

```java
public class Main {
    
    PApplet sketch;

    public Main(){
        sketch = new ChoroplethMap();
        sketch.init();
        // add a callback triggered after draw() in a sketch completed 
        // (as soon as a frame is ready)
        // sketch will search for method named "draw" in "this" instance
        sketch.registerMethod("draw", this);
        //stop rendering after the first frame
        sketch.noLoop();
    }

    // called after sketch's draw() completes
    public void draw(){
        sketch.save("test.jpg");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

Might be offtopic, but in the past I remember launching the sketch with [`PApplet.main()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#main-java.lang.String-):

```java
import processing.core.PApplet;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main(ChoroplethMap.class.getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

This is probably relevant only if `sketch.init()` doesn't launch the sketch already.

Comment: Yes, the PApplet does launch and displays the map. I tried putting the save() method directly in draw() like you said and interestingly it doesn't create a file whatsoever. 

I don't think the issue is a delay in rendering because I tried changing the color of the background to see if that would change the color of the saved image. That would mean it was only saving the background and the map/sketch didn't have time to initialize. But the resulting image stayed the same, completely blank, so its not reading anything?. Nonetheless I will try using `registerMethod()`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting! It's great the PApplet launches and displays the map. Just to isolate if the issue is with OpenGL rendering (might be worth changing `OPENGL` to `P2D` in `size()` to see if there's a diference) and drawing the Unfolding map, could try to save without calling `map.draw();` ? (e.g. if removing `map.draw()` saves a white image (`background(255)`)  instead of black then there's Unfolding interferes with rendering in a funny way, otherwise it might by something with the OpenGL animation thread an synching data so when you call save everything is accessible / ready to save)

Comment: I tried tinkering with the `map.draw()` like you said and in the process I realized it was making the images in the `build/` folder where all my binaries are instead of the `src/` folder where I have my code. That makes sense now that I think about it, I should use absolute paths from now on. One thing: having the image in the `draw()` method (like you have in the first code snippet) saves the image correctly, having it save in another class after calling init()/loadPixels() doesn't work. I'll just use the first method that works. Thanks a lot for your help, my issue has been fixed.

Comment: Happy to hear that! (and thank you for the vote/accept). Regarding init()/loadPixels(), did you get a chance try out the registerMethod option ? (I've updated the snippet using registerMethod btw). Additionally, you can make use of [`sketchPath()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#sketchPath-java.lang.String-) / [`dataPath()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#dataPath-java.lang.String-) if it helps organise generated files.

Comment: yeah, I tried out the registerMethod to run draw and it worked, but I find runSketch to be a simpler option. It's similar acutally, but I don't have to go through the motions of calling init() etc. Thanks for the help.